# Как внести данные в несколько таблиц за один раз

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть 4 модели. posts. comments, visitors и notifications. 
Когда человек добавляет комментарий к посту, он заполняет сам комментарий, свое имя и е-mail.

Маршруты выглядят вот так. Не совсем понятно как за один submit отправить все данные по своим таблицам.

```
resources :posts, only: [:index, :show, :new] do
    resources :comments
  end
  resources :visitors, [:create]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Все данные приходят вам в контролер. Забирает их из `params` и создаете необходимые записи.

В вашем случае это будет `comments_controller`. В `params` у вас будет `post_id`, а так же все данные из вашей формы.

Answer (score 4):

Оценим условия:

1. В форме создается комментарий. Значит центральное место играет модель `Comment`. И форма будет `form_for Comment.new do |f|`;
2. Ресурс `comments` вложен в `posts`, `url` у формы должен быть вида `POST posts/60/comments`. Корректируем: `form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f|`;
3. Поле комментария `message` задается в форме комментария: `f.text_area :message`;
4. Поля `email` и `fullname` - это поля `Visitor`, ассоциированной модели (в модели `Comment` у нас `belongs_to :visitor`). Для таких полей заводим в форме `fields_for :visitor do |ff|`

Итого форма будет примерно такой (slim):

```
= form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f|
  = f.text_area :message
  = f.fields_for :visitor do |ff|
    = ff.text_field :email
    = ff.text_field :fullname
```

Код контроллера будет примерно таким:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    Comment.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to post_path(params[:post_id])
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment)
          .permit(:message, visitor_attributes: [:email, :fullname])
          .merge(post_id: params[:post_id])
  end
end
```

Параметр `post_id` мы не передаем явно через форму, а выдергиваем из url (для `post/60/comments` - ID поста 60 будет лежать в `params[:post_id]`).

В модели Comment у нас будет примерно такое:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :visitor
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :visitor
end
```

Таким образом ActiveRecord по переданным с формы `email` и `fullname` создаст запись модели `Visitor` и привяжет ее к создаваемому комментарию.